# Waiting on a file handle until it has grown to some size

Tags: c++, windows

There is a component-A which downloads the content from some source and writes it to a file.
Another component-B which needs to wait for the Download+write operation by component-A to finish.

File Size is known before hand to component B.

Condition:
Component-A cannot signal that it has finished write operation.

Component B has to somehow identify that file has grown to the expected size and start reading it.

What is the best way to do this? Trivial way is to check for the size after some time intervals.

Is there a way to wait on file handle until it has grown to expected size?

Comment: Is the condition a limitation or a design choice? :v

Comment: it is limitation of the component-A. It is not aware of the file size. It gets content from some other source and keep writing it to the file. Some legacy things man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot wait on a file handle that way. Waiting on file handles is meaningful only if you use async operations (the handle becomes signaled whenever *any* such operation on it completes), and it's not recommended anyway.

A usable option would be to call [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but that comes with its own set of pitfalls (it works in terms of file names, not handles; file names might be long or short, no guarantee is given; you have to use the more complicated async workflow because the sync one offers nothing better than what you already have).

All in all, if your requirements are inviolate then using a timer doesn't sound bad, and it will certainly make for much simpler code.